# Sharepoint Delete items in ProcessBatchJob

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to delete items in batch processing but i am getting below error.

[image]

```
        SPQuery _query = new SPQuery();
        _query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>1</Value></Eq></Where>";
        SPListItemCollection _collection = _list.GetItems(_query);
        if (_collection.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder sbDelete = new StringBuilder();
            sbDelete.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Batch>");
            string command = "<Method><SetList Scope=\"Request\">" + _list.ID + "</SetList><SetVar Name=\"ID\">{0}</SetVar><SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Delete</SetVar></Method>";
            foreach (SPListItem item in _collection)
            {
                sbDelete.Append(string.Format(command, item.ID.ToString()));
            }
            sbDelete.Append("</Batch>");
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                _web.ProcessBatchData(sbDelete.ToString());
            }
            catch(SPException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            }
```

List is having only 2 columns and both text type, and i tried with other site and other webapplication  too(Sp2013, team site). But i am getting same error.

Not sure how to fix the error.
Can anyone help me how to find out this issue.

Regards
Sri

Comment: Are you sure your `_list.ID` is being properly resolved? Try console logging your `sbDelete` XML string and validating it in an XML editor to ensure your not passing malformed XML.

Comment: Hi Thanks for  your reply. I  tried deleting the items using  console and its working, with batch processing there also I am getting the error. Later I tried with deleting items one by one which is working. When I execute the code using batch process I can see  the uls log with the below error message    "Watson bucket parameters: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 4, ULSException14, 269cd32d "sharepoint foundation", 0f0011db "15.0.4571.0", d2cb6259 "onetutil.dll", 0f001385 "15.0.4997.0", 5a2f8907 "tue dec 12 08:45:11 2017", MISSING, 000d8871 "000d8871", c0000005 "c0000005", 3833376c "837l"